# Polynomial equation involving gamma function $\Gamma(x)$

Tags: polynomials, special-functions, gamma-function

I'm quite new to the world of special functions.

Recently for research purposes, I've arrived to the following equation:

$$\Gamma(x) = 20(5x+1),$$

with $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I've tried to exploit the fact that $\Gamma(x) = (x-1)!$ for integer $x$, and I found that
$x=7$ is a solution.

Anyway, I've arrived to this solution just by plugging iteratively integer numbers into the equation. I'm wondering if there is a calculus approach which can be used to find also non-integer solutions, if any, for problem in the form

$$\Gamma(x) = p(x),$$

where $p(x)$ is a polynomial.

For the proposed problem, I've found numerically that also $x \simeq -0.24$ is a solution

Comment: Analytically, no, but there are some users here who are adept at finding numerical solutions.

Comment: Thanks. I'm also able to solve it numerically. I was looking for closed form solutions, if any.

Then should I quit looking for them?

Comment: I don't want to give a definitive "yes" but probably, yeah. At least, I've seen questions here about solving equations involving the gamma function: none ever found meaningful closed forms, always it was numerics

Comment: @FShrike clear, thanks again!